# Setting Button Properties in ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms, listviewitem

I have a ListView which displays event bookings. If there is a time slot available, I want to make a booking button visible beside that data item. I have tried doing this in both the OnItemCreated and OnItemDataBound event handlers to no avail.

In this particular scenario, there are four results and all are available. However, the button only appears beside the last result. It's like something is being overwritten. I tried setting the ID property to something different in each round of the loop but that failed at runtime.

I also tried flipping the logic by setting the visibility of the button to false in the markup initially - three buttons would appear and no button beside the last data item.

I originally tried storing the Button control in ViewState and got the "not serializable" error. So I switched to storing the object in Session state.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="reserveButton" Text="Book Now" Visible="false"
        OnClick="ReserveButton_Click" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>

// After the DataBind() method in the search button handler
...
int rowCount = resultsDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;                  
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    if (resultsDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Available"].ToString().Contains("Available Time Slots"))
        {
            reserveButton = Session["ReserveButton"] as Button;
            reserveButton.Visible = true;
        }
}
...


protected void ResultsList_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is ListViewItem)
    {
        reserveButton = e.Item.FindControl("reserveButton") as Button; 
        Session["ReserveButton"] = reserveButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I was able to solve this as follows:

```
    protected void ResultsList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is ListViewItem)
        {
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            if (row["Available"].ToString().Contains("Available Time Slots"))
            {
                Button reserveButton = e.Item.FindControl("reserveButton") as Button;
                reserveButton.Visible = true;
            }
         }
    }
```